# mongoTempalte.save() an abstract class

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, polymorphism

I have an `Entity` class which is an abstract class containing basic fields. Consider the following code:

```
Entity entity = new DogEntity()
mongoTemplate.save(entity)
```

In this case, MongoDB will contain only the fields of `Entity`. On the other hand if we replace the first line with `DogEntity dogEntity = new DogEntity()` then all fields are inserted.

Moreover, in the first case, Spring Data will not add the `_class` field to the document.

Suppose you are given an abstract entity, how would you save it so all fields were inserted to the document?

I can of course have an `instanceof` check but this is a manual/tedious method that also needs to be maintained overtime.

What's the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and I'll share it for future readers:

base class (i.e. `Entity`) should not be annotated with `@Document`.